# Connect PHPMyAdmin/MySQL-Workbench to MySQL container (Docker)

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to connect to MySQL (inside a Docker container), through MySQL Workbench and PHPMyAdmin with no luck. I keep receiving the same error everytime I try to log in with both applications.

[PhpMyAdmin error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1CGt.png)

I've also tried to deploy both containers with this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mysqltest
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=userpassword
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:80"
```

...and again, no luck!

Do you have any suggestion,please?

Comment: Did you try to connect using both `user` and `root`  as the username while connecting from PHPMyAdmin? Do both give the same error? I think root should be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Basically, it was a version problem. With the latest version of MySQL (I think it's 8) there are some problem if I try to connect through Workbench or PHPMyAdmin.

So, I've tried to use an older version of MySQL (version 5) and I've created two containers with these commands:

```
docker run --name mysql_test  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=dbtest -e MYSQL_USER=user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=userpassword -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 -d mysql:5

docker run --name myadmin -d --link mysql_test:db -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

So I managed to log in successfully, using both credentials that I've created as environment variables.

Hope this can help somebody!